# Oracle APEX | DBMS_SCHEDULER | Spawning multiple jobs even on browser refresh

Tags: oracle-apex, jobs, apex

I have built an API that calls jar file through Apex dashboard using DBMS_SCHEDULER.
This dashboard has been working fine for 3 years now and recently I have observed its trying to spawn multiple jobs on refresh of the browser or refresh button on the apex screen.

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(arguments);

DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB (jobName , false);

Not sure of the reason, I have tried bouncing the apex also the application host hosting apex but no luck. Could someone help on this regard.

The jar file expects the below arguments -

java -jar /appworx/systems/dba_auto/Automation_Testing/automation-process-1.0.19.jar start -p UnityClone122 -t ACDEV -l DB_Post_Clone -k

Same is passed through apex.

This is triggered by the dynamic action of clicking on a button on the UI that calls the below PL/SQL code.

```
BEGIN

WHILE :CURRENT_GROUP IS NOT NULL 
LOOP
BEGIN
    
SELECT LOGICAL_GROUP_NAME INTO :CURRENT_GROUP  from AUTOMATION_execution_plan where seq_number = :SEQ_NUM and status = 'WAITING' 
order by execution_group_seq,execution_method_seq FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE('PRD_APEX_OS_RUNNER_ARGS',1,'start -p UnityClone122 -t ACDEV -l SOLR_Post_Clone -k <keypass>' );
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB ('PRD_APEX_OS_RUNNER_ARGS' , false);      
    

EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
dbms_output.put_line('File has no data');
EXIT;

WHEN OTHERS THEN 
dbms_output.put_line('Some Error occured');
EXIT; 
END;
END LOOP; 
END;
```

At present The API is triggering the event on clicking of the designated button as well as on clicking the browser refresh.
It is expected to trigger only on clicking of the designated button.

Also sharing the run details, as you can see, it has triggered two jobs in the same time.
select * from DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS where job_name ='PRD_APEX_OS_RUNNER_ARGS' order by log_id desc;

### LOG_ID  LOG_DATE                            OWNER               JOB_NAME                    STATUS

1752568 12/3/2023 9:27:50.716180 PM -07:00  XXARW_AUTOMATION    PRD_APEX_OS_RUNNER_ARGS     FAILED

1752566 12/3/2023 9:27:31.119282 PM -07:00  XXARW_AUTOMATION
PRD_APEX_OS_RUNNER_ARGS     FAILED

Thanks.

Comment: what is the behaviour you are expecting ? Can you describe that in more detail ?

Comment: I am expecting it to trigger the api only when the designated button is clicked, not on refresh. (Currently it gets triggered even on browser refresh)

Comment: You didn't answer my 2nd question. Please provide more info. How have you implemented this ? Please be as detailed as possible - we cannot see your application. Update the question with these details, do not put them in comments.

Comment: I have tried to provide the details, let me know what else are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can see is that the dynamic action has the attribute "fire on initialization" set to yes. That would cause this process to be fired on browser refresh. It should be set to "No".

This code could also be put in an after submit page process - that is the most logical place to put this. Change the button to have action "Submit Page", create a page process with the code above and put a server side condition of when button pressed on the process.